# Hex string convert to byte Java

Tags: java, arrays, hex, byte

I'm having problem because when use `getBytes()` method, java of course converts HEX code to ASCI which is not okey, I want to get array with bytes like:

```
[01, 00, 0A, 02, 00, 00, ....., 28, 72];
```

My code:

```
  byte array[] = { (byte) 0x1, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0x28 };

            Log.v("OUTPUT BYTE", Arrays.toString(array.getBytes()));
```

Current result:

```
[48, 49, 48, 48, 48, 97, 48, 50, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 55, 50, 50, 56]
```

I need HEX bytes in array.

Comment: "I need HEX bytes in array." There's no such thing as a "hex byte". There's just a byte. However, your code doesn't show where you're getting `data` from - and your log statement doesn't use `array3` at all. It sounds like you've missed out a whole bunch of context here.

Comment: ESP module receive command like that: 01 00 0a 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 72 28 as bytes but without conversion to ASCI, because it receives only HEX with separate bytes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it receives only HEX with separate bytes"? If it's receiving it as a byte array, there's no such thing as "receives only HEX" - it just receives the bytes. The code you've currently got in your question wouldn't compile, as a byte array doesn't have a `getBytes` method. My guess is that there's a string involved somewhere, but you haven't shown where.

Comment: Do you receive the bytes as bytes or as text? Which `getBytes` method is that? A byte is just 8 bits, so internally it’s always binary, but you should’t be concerned. You can always print the bytes out as hex again whenever you should need to.

Answer (score 2):

Sample code:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Hexa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte array3[] = { (byte) 0x1, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0,
                (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0,
                (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0x28 };

        String[] hexArray = new String[array3.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
            hexArray[i] = String.format("%02X ", array3[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(hexArray));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[01 , 00 , 0A , 02 , 00 , 00 , 00 , 00 , 00 , 00 , 00 , 00 , 00 , 00 , 00 , 00 , 72 , 28 ]
```

Comment: Type of hexArray should be Byte not String because TCP write uses Byte as input parameter.

Comment: @noname wrong the answer is okay; `array3` is the input parameter and hexArray a help variable for Arrays.toString/asList.

Comment: array3 is still converted to ASCI characters which is not right...: V/INPUT STRING: 01000a020000000000000000000000007228
V/INPUT BYTE: [1, 0, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 114, 40]

Comment: The java primitive type `byte` is an integer ranging from -128 to 127, whereas HEX are Strings that contains numbers and characters and leading zeros. So I think a byte[] datatype will not be able to store HEX Strings.

Comment: Only option would be sending data as ASCI and than converting on ESP to HEX and also result return as ASCI?

Comment: Found something as output i get: V/OUTPUT BYTE: [1, 0, 10, 2, 66, 72, -52, -51, 66, -58, 0, 0, 65, -72, 0, 0, -113, 27], now what i need to do if its negative value i need to countdown from 256 for example 256 - 52 = 204 which is CC in HEX and is right value... how would i fix that in byte array?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it works fine:

```
byte array3[] = { (byte) 0x1, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0x28 };

        Log.v("OUTPUT BYTE", Arrays.toString(data));
```

Comment: Now it's converting to ASCI code but should stay still same code [01, 00, 0A..., 27, 72].... 72 hex is 114 ASCI, but ofcourse ESP sensor receive this command as said before.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] data = { (byte) 0x1, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0,
    (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0,
    (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x0, (byte) 0x72, (byte) 0x28 };

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data.length * 4 + 2);
sb.append('[');
for (byte b : data) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X, ", 0xFF & b));
}
if (data.length != 0) {
    sb = sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2);
}
sb.append(']');
Log.v("OUTPUT_BYTE, sb.toString());
```

`%02X` would give capital hex digits, `%02x` small letter hex digits, both zero padded. As bytes are signed `(byte)0x80` actually is -128, so one needs to use an int masked by the byte: `0xFF & b`.

Adding a good initial capacity to StringBuilder means less reallocation of memory on append.